# Add missing data to a dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

My dictionary represents data from 24 hours. The dictionary fills dynamically depending of the hour. If at some hour there was no data, then it skips that hour. Please.

I would like to add the keys (which represent hours) that are not in the dictionary and give them a value of 0. The dictionary below is how I get the data:

```
{
 '0': 1, 
 '1': 1, 
 '4': 1, 
 '7': 1, 
 '8': 4, 
 '9': 6, 
 '10': 3, 
 '11': 12, 
 '12': 11, 
 '13': 9, 
 '14': 8, 
 '15': 7, 
 '16': 5, 
 '17': 9, 
 '18': 9, 
 '19': 5, 
 '20': 7, 
 '21': 4, 
 '22': 2, 
 '23': 4
}
```

This is how I would like to have my final dictionary:

```
{
 '0': 1, 
 '1': 1,
 '2': 0,
 '3': 0,
 '4': 1, 
 '5': 0,
 '6': 0,
 '7': 1, 
 '8': 4, 
 '9': 6, 
 '10': 3, 
 '11': 12, 
 '12': 11, 
 '13': 9, 
 '14': 8, 
 '15': 7, 
 '16': 5, 
 '17': 9, 
 '18': 9, 
 '19': 5, 
 '20': 7, 
 '21': 4, 
 '22': 2, 
 '23': 4
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why don’t you write a loop from 0 to 23, check if each value is contained in the dictionary, and if not, add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) in a `for` loop:

```
my_dict = {'0': 1, '1': 1, '4': 1, '7': 1, '8': 4, '9': 6, '10': 3, '11': 12, '12': 11, '13': 9, '14': 8, '15': 7, '16': 5, '17': 9, '18': 9, '19': 5, '20': 7, '21': 4, '22': 2, '23': 4}

my_dict = {str(i): my_dict.get(str(i), 0) for i in range(24)}
```